# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar los 20 últimos registros de la base de datos postgresql?

Tags: javascript, html5, base-de-datos, postgresql, mvc

Necesito tomar solamente los últimos 20 registros de mi base de datos, cual sería la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien es posible realizarlo con el filtro limitTo como se menciona, tiene que evaluar que cantidad de datos que se van a transferir desde la base de datos, es decir si vas a traer 1000 registros para solo mostrar 20 registros es mejor que solo transfieras los registros que necesites, desde la base de datos, en la sentecia sql, aca unos ejemplos de como usarlo de acuerdo a la base de datos
http://use-the-index-luke.com/es/sql/resultados-parciales/sentencia-top-n

Comment: Gracias @isaac, he probado con las opciones que se presentan, sin embargo, se me presenta un error y al parecer es por la sentencia que se encuentra más abajo.
la consulta se encuentra así:

@Query("SELECT a FROM Audit a ORDER BY a.whenau DESC FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY")
    public List<Audit> findAll();

Comment: Hola @CarmenA., te sugiero que edites tú pregunta con lo que has realizado, el error que se presenta, adicional el motor de base de datos que usas y si usas un framework para base de datos indicar cual, de esta forma la comunidad te puede seguir ayudando.

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza el filtro [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) que te permite mostrar la cantidad de elementos especificada:

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 
  $scope.numbers = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
   $scope.numbers.push(i);
 }
 
 console.log("El array number tiene " + $scope.numbers.length + " elementos");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
     <div ng-repeat="n in numbers |limitTo:5">
      {{n}}
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```